# In Git, how do I separate a branch from its upstream branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch that was built off of another branch, but should actually be a separate branch off of master (they are distinct features).  Right now I believe I have this :

```
...- master
        \  
         A1 - A2
               \
                B1
```

What I want is for none of the changes in the A branch to be in the B branch.  The result should be:

```
         B1
        /
...-master
         \   
          A1 - A2
```

So far I've tried `git branch --set-upstream-to=master`
and  `git rebase master` (while on B) but that's not doing what I want.

Comment: You'll need an interactive rebase `git rebase -i` It will allow you to select the commits you want to rebase. Checking out the branch that's currently on `B1` and doing a `git rebase -i master` (and then just selecting `B1` for rebase) should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a [`rebase --onto`](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/git-rebase-onto):

```
git checkout B1
git rebase --onto master A2 B1
```

Comment: This looks like the most succinct way to do what I asked for.  If I had made more commits to the B branch, would I want to use the latest one (say B3) in the statement or does that mark where the rebase starts?

Comment: All commits *after* A2 up to the current HEAD (B1, or, after several commits,  B3) are rebased onto master

Answer (score 0):

one way may also be to create a new branch from master and cherry-pick the commits done on B1

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b B1 #(either delete beforehand B1 (git branch -D B1) or use a different name here)
git cherry-pick SHA-Commit-on-B1
...
```

since cherry-pick supports range of commits, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664543/1657377 this may also be worth a try